# Why do my client side events in remix not fire?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix, remix.run

I am using remix.run to build a web app. To implement search functionality, I added the onKeyDown attribute to an input tag within one of my components and a function to fire.

```
<input className="input" type="search" placeholder="Search" onKeyDown={renewList} />
```

Somewhere above that:

```
function renewList() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

Somehow, the event doesn't fire though. I made sure I added the `<Scripts />` tag in the root file and I even searched the bundle `remix build` created - my function and the `onKeyDown` attribute were included correctly. I tried to reproduce the error in a blank project with no success - the alert popped up as soon as I started to type.

Is this some common error with an easy solution?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you say it works in a blank project, but not your current one? Do you see anything in dev console? Any errors there will prevent scripts from running.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I accidentally had some server side code bundled for the client, causing some trouble. I could fix that using one of your github repos. Now I get a different error: `Expected server HTML to contain a matching <head> in <html>`. I'm not really sure how to go about that, even after hours of googling.

Comment: Alright, i got it. For anyone finding this in the future: Check if you use any browser extensions that insert scripts at the beginning of your html. That was the issue for me.